# Setting Up Google Analytics Goal w/ Regular Expression

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to set up a goal in analytics to track how many times a form is completed. When the form is completed, "#thankyou" (without the quotes) is added to the end of the url... example: http://www.example.com/formpage#thankyou.

How do I set up the Analytics goal to look for any URL that has #thankyou at the end? I think I need to use a regular expression, but can't quite figure it out.

Screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a head match. A regular expression would have to look for a string that ends with #thankyou and is preceeded by any number of arbitrary characters, so that should be

```
.*#thankyou.html$
```

where "." means "any character", "*" means "any number of the preceeding character" (any in that case) and the dollar signs means "ends with the preceeding character".

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not include data for URLs with fragment identifiers by default. You'll need to slightly modify your tracking code in order for **#thankyou** to show in your reports. Once that's configured, your goal will start showing. Modified code below:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.hash + location.search]);
```